# How to calculate the total number of 1-hour intervals in a sequence of intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

Let's consider the following dataframe of **sorted** time intervals:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s="""start_time,end_time
2022-01-01 12:30:00,2022-01-01 12:45:00
2022-01-01 13:05:00,2022-01-01 13:50:00
2022-01-01 14:00:00,2022-01-01 14:20:00
2022-01-01 16:00:00,2022-01-01 16:45:00
2022-01-01 17:20:00,2022-01-01 17:35:00
2022-01-01 17:45:00,2022-01-01 18:30:00
2022-01-01 19:00:00,2022-01-01 19:25:00"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=",")
df.start_time = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time)
df.end_time = pd.to_datetime(df.end_time)

          start_time               end_time
0    2022-01-01 12:30:00    2022-01-01 12:45:00
1    2022-01-01 13:05:00    2022-01-01 13:50:00
2    2022-01-01 14:00:00    2022-01-01 14:20:00
3    2022-01-01 16:00:00    2022-01-01 16:45:00
4    2022-01-01 17:20:00    2022-01-01 17:35:00
5    2022-01-01 17:45:00    2022-01-01 18:30:00
6    2022-01-01 19:00:00    2022-01-01 19:25:00
```

The idea is that an 1-hour interval is basically calculated in the following way:
we start with the `start_time` of the first interval and we add 1 hour to it.

If the resulting timestamp is **within** one of the following intervals that are in the dataframe, then we repeat the process by adding 1-hour to this new timestamp and so on.

If, however, the resulting timestamp is not within, but **between** two intervals, then we continue by adding 1-hour to the `start_time` of the next interval.

The input would be the dataframe above.

The process is:
We start by adding 1-hour to the `start_time` of the first interval:

1. 12:30 + 1H -> 13:30 (13:30 is a timestamp that is within one of the available intervals. In particular, it is within 13:05 - 13:50, which is an interval in our dataframe. We shall, then, continue from 13:30).
2. 13:30 + 1H -> 14:30 (14:30 is not contained in any of our df intervals - we pick the closest `start_time` after 14:30)
3. 16:00 + 1H -> 17:00 (17:00 not included in any interval of our dataframe)
4. 17:20 + 1H -> 18:20 (18:20 is included between 17:45 - 18:30, which is also an interval that we have in our dataframe)
5. 18:20 + 1H -> 19:20 (it is included in our last interval)
6. 19:20 + 1H -> 20:20 (we have reached or surpassed (greater or equal) the `end_time` of our last inteval, so we stop). *If, for instance though, the last `end_time` in the dataframe was 19:20:00 instead of 19:25:00 then we would have stopped in the previous step (since we reached a timestamp greater or equal to the very last `end_time`).*

Output: 6
(The output in the alternative case that the very last `end_time` is equal to 19:20:00 would have been equal to 5).

The output stands for the total number of times that the process of adding 1H was repeated.

As far as code is concerned I have thought of maybe using `.shift()` somehow but I am not sure how. The problem is that when the resulting timestamp is not between an available interval, then we should search for the closest following `start_time`.

Comment: It might be helpful to post a few more examples, and perhaps a longer starting dataframe

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: @dermen I have added a longer starting dataframe and expanded my example to make it more clear hopefully!

Comment: @itprorh66 I have included an input and output to make it more clear :) I have not included any code because I cannot translate the required logic into pandas-like code. I have thought of a for loop, but I'd like to avoid it (for performance reasons).

Comment: Given your explanation and your input data, I still can't figure out what you are trying to get as a result.  Please add a sample of what you expect the output to look like.

Comment: @itprorh66 The output is simply an integer number stating the number of times that we managed to add an 1-hour interval by following the process described above. In our example, this is done 6 times. So, the output would simply be: 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that vectorization (i.e. parallelization) is possible, because the process at each step depends on the result of the calculations at the previous steps. The solution in any case will be some kind of iteration. And the speed of work will depend primarily on the algorithm you choose to work with.

It seems to me that a good algorithm would be to see if the `end_time` and `start_time` of neighboring records fall into the same *hour step* as if we were measuring *length* by hours starting from some point. For this we can use integer division:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """start_time,end_time
2022-01-01 12:30:00,2022-01-01 12:45:00
2022-01-01 13:05:00,2022-01-01 13:50:00
2022-01-01 14:00:00,2022-01-01 14:20:00
2022-01-01 16:00:00,2022-01-01 16:45:00
2022-01-01 17:20:00,2022-01-01 17:35:00
2022-01-01 17:45:00,2022-01-01 18:30:00
2022-01-01 19:00:00,2022-01-01 19:25:00"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), parse_dates=[0, 1])

data = df.to_numpy().flatten()
start = data[0]
step = pd.Timedelta(1, 'H')   # hour as a unit of length
count = 0
for x, y in data[1:-1].reshape(-1, 2):
    # x is previous end_time
    # y is next start_time
    length = (x-start) // step + 1
    if start + step*length < y:
        count += length
        start = y
integer, decimal = divmod((data[-1] - start) / step, 1)
count += integer if decimal == 0 else integer+1

print(f'{count = }')
```

Comment: I am trying to understand what length stands for. As far as I understand (x - start) actually stands for the duration of an interval which then gets divided (integer division) by an 1-hour step, which I guess is supposed to tell us how many full hours the interval lasted. But finally, I can see that `+1` is added to the result above. Why is that?

Comment: @ttsak It's the last step we do before we get in between neighboring `end_time, start_time` pair. If that happens we start all the game from the next nearest `start_time`.

Comment: I think that there might be an edge case: if, for example, we modified the last `end_time` from `19:25:00` to `19:20:00`, then wouldn't the result of the above snippet still be `count = 6`? However, the result should have been `count = 5`. My point is that in case `(x - start) // step` equals to `(x - start) / step` (i.e. float division has the same result with integer division) then we should not add +1 to the length variable. What do you think? :-)

Comment: @ttsak I think that you should be more clear in terms of what it means to be **withing** and **between** intervals. Are your intervals closed, left closed, right closed, open?

Comment: I had not thought of it that way, you are right that I was indeed not clear enough. My intervals are closed: within was supposed to mean anywhere inside an interval (closed interval), whereas between means anywhere outside of an interval (closed interval). However, if for some reason we land on the exact same timestamp of the `end_time` of the last interval then we should not continue (hence the edge case I described above). I'm sorry for not specifying these in advance!

Comment: Do you make a step if all your intervals are within one hour? Let's say that the very last `end_time` you have in your dataset is 0:59:00

Comment: If all my intervals are within one hour (closed), then that would have been exactly one step. Even if the very last `end_time` was 00:01:00 (total duration of all intervals that equals to one hour exactly) that would have been 1 total step as well. Any millisecond beyond that and we'd need to have an extra step. So, for example, if the very last `end_time` was 00:01:01, then that would have been two steps.

Comment: @ttsak Well, in this case, I expect the code to work _almost_ fine (**upd. an additional constraint on the last step is one check at the end of the computation**). If not, then some test cases may shed some light on the problem. But anyway, the main idea is that you have non-linear process which hardly can be vectorized. So to make the work faster you need to look for an algorithm as close to O(n) as possible.

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty clear now as to why vectorization would not work in this case. By the way, I have slightly editted the description to clarify the situation that we described above! The only thing that I can think of is comparing the float and integer division results for the final step before adding that extra +1.

Comment: Replacing the last line with this will do the trick: first `i, d = divmod((data[-1] - start) / step, 1)` and then just `count += i if d == 0 else (i+1)`. All it does it that it makes sure to add that +1 if the final step does not divide the dividend perfectly (i.e. `quotient = 0`). Could you please edit if you agree? :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if pandas is really necessary here, but here is a solution following your logic.

```
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np
count = 0
start = df.loc[0,'start_time']
while 1:
    count += 1
    print("hour interval start:", start)
    end_of_interv = start + timedelta(hours=1)
    new_row = np.searchsorted(df.end_time, end_of_interv)
    if new_row >= len(df):
        break
    s, e = df.loc[new_row, ['start_time', 'end_time']]
    if end_of_interv < s:
        start = s
    elif s < end_of_interv < e:
        start = end_of_interv
print("Number of intervals counted: %d" % count)
#hour interval start: 2022-01-01 12:30:00
#hour interval start: 2022-01-01 13:30:00
#hour interval start: 2022-01-01 16:00:00
#hour interval start: 2022-01-01 17:20:00
#hour interval start: 2022-01-01 18:20:00
#hour interval start: 2022-01-01 19:20:00
#Number of intervals counted: 6
```

You should test this on a few more examples with different intervals (e.g. some longer than 1 hour) and start times, and verify it produces the answers you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `start_time` as index allows using the [`pandas.Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html)
method, which makes searching for the next starting point easier. Here, is a solution based on it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
s = """start_time,end_time
2022-01-01 12:30:00,2022-01-01 12:45:00
2022-01-01 13:05:00,2022-01-01 13:50:00
2022-01-01 14:00:00,2022-01-01 14:20:00
2022-01-01 16:00:00,2022-01-01 16:45:00
2022-01-01 17:20:00,2022-01-01 17:35:00
2022-01-01 17:45:00,2022-01-01 18:30:00
2022-01-01 19:00:00,2022-01-01 19:25:00"""

def is_in_range(var):
    # check if the given timestamp exists withing any of the range in the dataframe
    in_range = df.loc[(df['start_time']<=var) & (df['end_time']> var)].shape[0]
    # increment by one hour if it exists
    if in_range:
        var = var + pd.Timedelta(1,'H')
    
    # If not, find the next closest start time (=index)
    else:
        var = df.index[df.index.get_indexer([var],'bfill')][0]
    return var, in_range

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
df[["start_time", "end_time"]] = df[["start_time", "end_time"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
 
glb_start_time = df.loc[0,'start_time']
glb_end_time = df.loc[df.index[-1], 'end_time']

df.index= df['start_time']

count = 0
while glb_start_time< glb_end_time:
    glb_start_time, in_range = is_in_range(glb_start_time)
    if in_range:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def update_df(frame, check_time, hour):
    # returns: new_check_time, count
    # updates the data frame
    
    frame = frame[frame['end_time'] > check_time] 
    if frame.shape[0] == 0 : return None, 0 # exceeds the latest time
    
    filt = frame['start_time'] <= check_time
    frame = frame[~filt].reset_index(drop=True)
    if filt[filt].any(): return check_time + hour, 1 # it is insdie interval
    else: return frame.loc[0, 'start_time'] + hour, 1 # it is not in the interval
    
hour = pd.to_timedelta(1, 'h')    
check_time = df.loc[0, 'start_time'] + hour
total_count = 1
while True:
    new_check_time, count = update_df(df, check_time, hour)
    
    total_count += count
    if new_check_time is None: break
    else: check_time = new_check_time
    
print(total_count)
```